# Exposing a shell-script dump to Network Monitoring tool

Tags: linux, shell, snmp, nagios, net-snmp

In the recent past i have explored network monitoring solutions like ZenOSS, Nagios, Zabbix etc.

However, for my requirements, i had to write a shell-script which dumps (#echo) 
certain values which were otherwise not included in the mentioned monitoring solutions.

Now, i wonder which Network Monitoring tool(s) could i integrate my shell script with?

I am aware that most of the tools work on SNMP model but are there any such tools which could take data from Linux terminal dump or say from a log file written by the script and present it to the Monitoring tool/system.

I am looking such sort of integration if possible.
Any sort of intermediate conversions feasible can be adapted to too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved.

Ultimately, i ended up integrating my custom script with the Nagios Monitoring Tool. The echo commands perfectly dump the script parameters on the Nagios web interface.

Had to use the NRPE daemon-check_nrpe approach for this.